# aSync Task can't be executed twice

Tags: java, android, json, android-asynctask, http-post

I'm working on app which needs to upload a file to server. But to upload the files it needs to login (working) then get the url (working) then uploading (Force Close)

The logcat:

```
10-13 14:10:27.494: E/AndroidRuntime(26578): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
10-13 14:10:27.494: E/AndroidRuntime(26578): java.lang.IllegalStateException: Cannot execute task: the task has already been executed (a task can be executed only once)
10-13 14:10:27.494: E/AndroidRuntime(26578):    at android.os.AsyncTask.executeOnExecutor(AsyncTask.java:578)
10-13 14:10:27.494: E/AndroidRuntime(26578):    at android.os.AsyncTask.execute(AsyncTask.java:534)
10-13 14:10:27.494: E/AndroidRuntime(26578):    at com.spxc.bayfiles.FilesActivity.onOptionsItemSelected(FilesActivity.java:294)
10-13 14:10:27.494: E/AndroidRuntime(26578):    at com.actionbarsherlock.app.SherlockActivity.onMenuItemSelected(SherlockActivity.java:208)
10-13 14:10:27.494: E/AndroidRuntime(26578):    at com.actionbarsherlock.ActionBarSherlock.callbackOptionsItemSelected(ActionBarSherlock.java:603)
10-13 14:10:27.494: E/AndroidRuntime(26578):    at com.actionbarsherlock.internal.ActionBarSherlockNative.dispatchOptionsItemSelected(ActionBarSherlockNative.java:93)
10-13 14:10:27.494: E/AndroidRuntime(26578):    at com.actionbarsherlock.app.SherlockActivity.onOptionsItemSelected(SherlockActivity.java:159)
10-13 14:10:27.494: E/AndroidRuntime(26578):    at android.app.Activity.onMenuItemSelected(Activity.java:2566)
10-13 14:10:27.494: E/AndroidRuntime(26578):    at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow.onMenuItemSelected(PhoneWindow.java:986)
10-13 14:10:27.494: E/AndroidRuntime(26578):    at com.android.internal.view.menu.MenuBuilder.dispatchMenuItemSelected(MenuBuilder.java:735)
10-13 14:10:27.494: E/AndroidRuntime(26578):    at com.android.internal.view.menu.MenuItemImpl.invoke(MenuItemImpl.java:152)
10-13 14:10:27.494: E/AndroidRuntime(26578):    at com.android.internal.view.menu.MenuBuilder.performItemAction(MenuBuilder.java:874)
10-13 14:10:27.494: E/AndroidRuntime(26578):    at com.android.internal.view.menu.ActionMenuView.invokeItem(ActionMenuView.java:547)
10-13 14:10:27.494: E/AndroidRuntime(26578):    at com.android.internal.view.menu.ActionMenuItemView.onClick(ActionMenuItemView.java:115)
10-13 14:10:27.494: E/AndroidRuntime(26578):    at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:4240)
10-13 14:10:27.494: E/AndroidRuntime(26578):    at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:17721)
10-13 14:10:27.494: E/AndroidRuntime(26578):    at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:730)
10-13 14:10:27.494: E/AndroidRuntime(26578):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
10-13 14:10:27.494: E/AndroidRuntime(26578):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
10-13 14:10:27.494: E/AndroidRuntime(26578):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5103)
10-13 14:10:27.494: E/AndroidRuntime(26578):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
10-13 14:10:27.494: E/AndroidRuntime(26578):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:525)
10-13 14:10:27.494: E/AndroidRuntime(26578):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:737)
10-13 14:10:27.494: E/AndroidRuntime(26578):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:553)
10-13 14:10:27.494: E/AndroidRuntime(26578):    at de.robv.android.xposed.XposedBridge.main(XposedBridge.java:112)
10-13 14:10:27.494: E/AndroidRuntime(26578):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

My code: (handleJsonObject):

```
private void handleJsonObject(JSONObject object) {

        try {
            sUpload = object.getString("uploadUrl");            
            HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();

            //post request to send the video 

            File sdCardRoot = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory();
            File myDir = new File(sdCardRoot, "Download");

            HttpPost httppost = new HttpPost(sUpload);
            StrictMode.ThreadPolicy policy = new StrictMode.ThreadPolicy.Builder().permitAll().build();
            StrictMode.setThreadPolicy( policy);
            FileBody video_file1 = new FileBody(new File(myDir + "/test.txt"));
            MultipartEntity reqEntity = new MultipartEntity();
            reqEntity.addPart("file=", video_file1);                    
            httppost.setEntity(reqEntity);

            // DEBUG
            System.out.println( "executing request " + httppost.getRequestLine( ) );
            HttpResponse response = null;
            try {
                response = httpclient.execute( httppost );
            } catch (ClientProtocolException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            HttpEntity resEntity = response.getEntity( );

            // DEBUG
            System.out.println( response.getStatusLine( ) );
            if (resEntity != null) {
              try {
                System.out.println( EntityUtils.toString( resEntity ) );
            } catch (org.apache.http.ParseException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            } // end if
            if (resEntity != null) {
              try {
                resEntity.consumeContent( );
            } catch (IOException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            } // end if

            httpclient.getConnectionManager( ).shutdown( );


        } catch (JSONException e) {
            Log.e("log_tag", "Error parsing data: " + e.toString());
            Crouton.makeText(this, "Something went wrong!", Style.ALERT).show();
        }
    }
```

The code (aSync) Which calls the post code (handleJsonObject):

```
asyncTask.setJsonListener(new JsonListener() {
                public void onObjectReturn(JSONObject object) {
                    handleJsonObject(object);
                }
            });
            asyncTask.execute("http://api.bayfiles.net/v1/file/uploadUrl?session=" + sessionId);
```

I can't figure out why the code won't work?
Any help is much appreciated!

Comment: The error is originating in your activity.  You need to post that code.

Answer (score 29, accepted):

As the exception itself explains, you cannot execute an `AsyncTask` more than once, unless you create a `new` instance of it and call `.execute`.

For example:

```
async = new AsyncTask();
async.execute();
```

*in order to execute more than once, you need to re-create the instance (using `new`) the number of times you want to **execute** it.

Comment: i simply call it once? dont i ?

Answer (score 0):

I use this code and it works for me:

```
    if ((eliminar_op_async != null) && eliminar_op_async.getStatus() == AsyncTask.Status.RUNNING) {
        if (eliminar_op_async.isCancelled()) {
            eliminar_op_async = new EliminarOperacion();

            eliminar_op_async.execute(id_operacion,posicion_operacion);
        }
        else {
            // Nada
        }
    }

    if ((eliminar_op_async != null) && eliminar_op_async.getStatus() == AsyncTask.Status.PENDING) {
        eliminar_op_async.execute(id_operacion,posicion_operacion);
    }

    if ((eliminar_op_async != null) && eliminar_op_async.getStatus() == AsyncTask.Status.FINISHED) {
        eliminar_op_async = new EliminarOperacion();

        eliminar_op_async.execute(id_operacion,posicion_operacion);
    }

    if (eliminar_op_async == null) {
        eliminar_op_async = new EliminarOperacion();

        eliminar_op_async.execute(id_operacion,posicion_operacion);
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can cancel by calling async instance with async.cancel(true) so that you can ensure there is only one instance of async

Answer (score -1):

You cannot execute AsyncTask more than once,therefore to fix this error, simply wrap it in a condition like this :
                   async = new AsyncTask();

```
                 if (async==null){

                   async.execute();

                    }
```

This error usually occurs when you are trying to run Asynctask in a viewpager. When you run asynctask in a fragment and swipe to the next fragment, returning to the previous fragment triggers a re- execution of the asynctask in  that fragment causing the app to crash. Therefore you have to check if the asynctask has already been executed by wrapping it in a condition.